# What i and n stand for in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ironpython

I've been writing a program to pick random words from my list. However, to do that I had to imitate some solutions on the internet, and I succeeded. 
Unfortunately, there is something that I can't understand in my work.

```
def repeat(pic_word, n):
    for i in range(n):
        pic_word()
```

My question is what is the meaning of i in "for i in range"?

Comment: Note that in the example you've shown `i` isn't used, and is somewhat meaningless - it's therefore conventional to use `for _ in range(...):` to indicate this.

Answer (score 0):

i is just the name of a variable, in this case an integer. Most programmers will use i for the outermost for loop when iterating through a list of numbers.

What this loop is doing is creating a range from 0 to n (some number). Then it's looking at all the numbers in there, one at a time. In this case the loop is running pic_word() n times.